# Count xml nodes in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, xmlnode

How do I count total number of xml nodes from xml file in windows phone?
here is my XML file:

```
<root>
  <child>
    <id>1234</id>
    <name>abcd</name>
  </child>
</root>
```

the above example is for demo, there can be mulitple

```
<child>
```

in xml file,

Now, my question is that I want to count total number of

```
<id> and <name> from XML file
```

so how to solve it?

Comment: Do you want to get count of all nodes pr onli child node.

Comment: @Jaihind i want to count total number of <id> and <name>..
I am searching for your help brother..where were you lost?

Answer (score 2):

use this code to get id count:

```
int count = XDocument.Load("Test.xml").XPathSelectElements("root/child/id").Count();
```

use this code to get name count

```
int count = XDocument.Load("Test.xml").XPathSelectElements("root/child/name").Count();
```

Comment: use this above code for id and name count ,i have tested this code .It is working for me

Comment: thank you brother, but i am not getting XPathSelectElements, how do I get it?I am using visual studio 2013,windows phone 8.

Comment: also use System.Xml.XPath.dll..it is important

Comment: XPathSelectElements comes under using System.Xml.XPath library; first add System.Xml.XPath.dll and then add using System.Xml.XPath statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with Xquery by using the count-function like (I hope I remeber the syntax correctly):

count(//child): here you would count all child-nodes from root of the document or
count(//root/child)
maybe it also workes like this:
//root/count(child)

Comment: can you show me by code or syntax, I don't know..thanks for your quick reply.